# Android Voice Recognition in background and convert to text

Tags: android, background, voice-recognition

I have an app idea which recognizes a human voice from Android OS and convert a speech into text. I have done the process in foreground. But the same I need in implemented in Background.

For this, I think the approach. My approach is I get the activity background state and from there I invoked the service. after that whenever the application will be in the background every time the service will be invoked. 
I have no idea How can I implement this.

My Foreground Source Code as

```
private void promptSpeechInput(){
                //----takes user input----//
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                //----which language users will speak
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
                //-----
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                        getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
   /**
     * Receiving speech input
     * */


  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
           ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                  txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Calling a `service` from `activity`

```
 @Override
        protected void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            Log.e("Application background", "Background");
            //-----Create Service From here and identify the state of background
           Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,BackgroundService.class);
           startService(serviceIntent);
    }
```

BackgroundService.java

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    private SpeechRecognizer speech;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e("servicecreate", "service");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "OnCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e("servicedestroy", "service");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "OnDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("servicecstart", "service");
    }
}
```